# Explicit specialization using variadic parameters within variadic templated class [MSVS '12: Nov. '12 CTP: error C3522]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to expand a class's variadic template type list within a child method as such:

```
template<typename... P>
struct Foo
{
    template<P...> // error C3522: 'P' : parameter
                   // pack cannot be expanded in this context
    static void Bar(P... a){}
};
```

What is wrong with this code, or is it just a MSVS '12: Nov. '12 CTP bug?

(Yes, I know the explicit template specialization in this example is redundant.)

The above is the simplest case that I get to reproduce the error. The full code is:

```
template<typename FuncSignature>
class Callback;

template<typename R, typename... P>
class Callback<R (P...)>
{
public:

    Callback()                    : func(0), obj(0) {}

    Callback& operator=(const Callback& rhs)
    { obj = rhs.obj; func = rhs.func; return *this; }

private:
    typedef R (*FuncType)(const void*, P...);
    Callback(FuncType f, const void* o) : func(f), obj(o) {}

private:
    FuncType func;
    const void* obj;

    template<typename FR, typename... FP>
    friend class FreeCallbackFactory;
};

template<typename R, typename... P>
class FreeCallbackFactory
{
private:
    template<R (*Func)(P...)>
    static R Wrapper(const void*, P... a)
    {
        return (*Func)(a...);
    }

public:
    template<R (*Func)(P...)>
    inline static Callback<R (P...)> Bind()
    {
        return Callback<R (P...)>
            (&FreeCallbackFactory::Wrapper<Func>, 0);
    }
};
template<typename R, typename... P>
inline FreeCallbackFactory<R, P...>
    GetCallbackFactory(R (*)(P...))
{
    return FreeCallbackFactory<R, P...>();
}

void Test(){}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
Callback<void ()> cb = GetCallbackFactory(&Test).Bind<&Test>()
}
```

It compiles fine in g++ so I'm assuming just a compiler bug, and continued findings still only point to this, are there any possible workarounds for this other than explicitly expanding them out one by one?

---

**Edit:** [This has been reported to the compiler team as a bug and a patch will be in the next release of the compiler. [Link]](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773637/codename-milan-variadic-template-arguments-fail-to-expand-within-wrapping-template#details)

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct put I doubt that it does what you intended it to do: The declaration

```
template <P...>
static void Bar(P... a);
```

declares a function taking `P...` values as template argument and as function argument. That is, the elements of `P` need to be of a type allowing non-type parameters (e.g., integers, pointers, or references) and you'd need to provide their respective values as template parameters when calling the function. The call to a function like this would look something like this (although it seems neither gcc nor clang require the template parameters to be passed):

```
Foo<int, int>::Bar<1, 2>(3, 4);
```

That said, based on the error messages generated by both gcc and clang it seems that they won't let you create a specialization of member function templates but I haven't verified this in the standard. I think, you should probably just leave out the template declaration and use

```
static void Bar(P... a);
```

Comment: This is pertaining to MSVC: Nov. 12 CTP. That was the simplest case I got that reproduced the error. I've updated the question with my full code which does compile fine under GCC, although I have to use MSVC for the of the project. Thanks for the help so far and adding to my understanding of non-type params.

Answer (score 0):

To me the code does not look correct. The pack expansion P... expands to a set of types. Depending on what you aim to achieve the correct thing to do would be to remove the `template<P...>` part, in which case each class template instance has one Bar() method with the same parameters as the class. The other would be that this is an unrelated parameter pack in which case an unbounded set of methods is generated, in that case you must declare the method something like:

```
template<typename... U> static void Bar(U...);
```

reusing the name P would not be very useful, I guess.